# How to say fractions and ratios in Japanese

Tags: grammar

I am trying to remember how to say things such as 1 cup of water per 3 cups milk, but in a more ambiguous manner.

Is it along the lines of １分水の３分牛乳 but with 1(smaller part)の(bigger part)?
If I want to address the bigger part first as I do in the following example, can I relate it in the same fashion of bigger thing as a topicは(smallerの分）を(some stuff)?

specifically:

> 表で一般のプロットにプロットの分を題名を作ってあげられます。

I want to say for the regular plots in a table, you can create titles for the smaller/sub plots.

Answer (score 2):

> 1 cup of water per 3 cups milk

There are various ways to say as follows for the above example.
We usually say bigger part first.

1. 牛乳{ぎゅうにゅう}3カップに水{みず}1カップの割合{わりあい}
2. 3カップの牛乳[当]{あ}たり1カップの水
3. 3カップの牛乳に対{たい}して1カップの水
4. 牛乳3に水1の割合
5. 牛乳3、水1の割合
6. 牛乳1カップに水[1/3]{さんぶんのいち}カップ

> specifically: 表で一般のプロットにプロットの分を題名を作ってあげられます。 I want to say for the regular plots in a table, you can create titles for the smaller/sub plots.

We cannot answer your above question. Please express it a little more accurately.